# maven base directory default

Tags: eclipse, maven

I imported a Tycho-Maven project with hundreds of packages.  It is organized into chunks so I imported the same way into my workspace, creating a folder under which all the packages are located

```
>org.eclipse.scada.base
    >org.eclipse.scada.base-p2
    >org.eclipse.scada.base-parent
    etc etc
```

Now every time I try to run Maven build, I get an error "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\Ravi\git\org.eclipse.scada.base) which is the top level without any POM.

I traced this to the "Base directory" in maven defaulting to the top level"org.eclipse.scada.base" instead of "org.eclipse.scada.base/org.eclipse.scada.base-p2".  If I change the base directory, it builds fine.  Is there a way to make the package root as the default base directory globally.  That will save me from having to change the base every time.

Comment: Can you show where your pom files are located ? and are you running from command line ?

Comment: The POM files are located under the sub

Comment: The POM files are located under the sub
>org.eclipse.scada.base
    >org.eclipse.scada.base-p2
       >src
         POM.xml
    >org.eclipse.scada.base-parent
         POM.xml
    etc etc

I am running on windows from eclipse by right clicking on the POM clicking Maven Build... to bring up the configuration window and hit run.  I have been changing the base directory on the configuration window that comes up.

Comment: >org.eclipse.scada.base
        >org.eclipse.scada.base-p2
          >src
           POM.xml
         >org.eclipse.scada.base-parent
         POM.xml
    etc etc

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting the all the projects and then importing them back into working sets keeping the original project structure.  Then I don't have to change the base directory.  This is probably the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Go to run configurations --> maven--> check for base configuration text box --> browse for options --> point your project